# Exception by start new activity

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, start-activity

I try to start a new activity then I get error "Unfortunally app....." from the emulator.

```
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3662)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at de.basti12354.tage.uebungen.Tag1$1$1.run(Tag1.java:115)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-24 12:41:53.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have add the new activity to the ManifestLayout.

That's my code to start the new activity called Uebung2.class.

```
    @Override
        public void run() {
            while (Running){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);}

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        number+=1;
                        textfield.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                        if (number>5) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(null, Uebung2.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }

                    }
                } );
            }

        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Comment: why would you think this `Intent intent = new Intent(null, Uebung2.class);` would work? A context parameter is explicitly asked, it is not optional or anything, there is no reason not to pass a parameter here. Plus it should occur to you that an NPE is often caused by something being ... null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(null, Uebung2.class);
```

You must supply `Intent` constructor a valid `Context` instead of a `null`.

What to use depends on the context (sic) where your code is. Use `ActivityName.this` to refer to the outer activity class in case the nested inner class is in fact in an activity.

Also, consider using just `handler.postDelayed()` for producing a delay instead of `Thread.sleep()` in a background thread.

Comment: What is the right context in my case? I can't use this like I always do :)

Answer (score 2):

Your context is null

```
Intent intent = new Intent(null, Uebung2.class);
```

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Uebung2.class);
```

Also i don't see any network or background computation done. So using just the handler is a better choice if you want a dealy.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the context in the activity like this.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Uebung2.class);
 (or)
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uebung2.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a context of your class intially.

```
Context context = Activityname.this;
```

Then change your Intent as follows

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Uebung2.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass context as a null. So need to change from

```
Intent intent = new Intent(null, Uebung2.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Uebung2.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

> Intent intent = new Intent(null, Uebung2.class);

with this:

> Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, Uebung2.class);

(or)

> Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uebung2.class);

**And don't forget to mention activities in Androidmanifest.xml**

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Uebung2.class);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Youactivityname.this, Uebung2.class);

//Youactivityname mean the activity you was in like Mainactivity
```